# Mining stops after some time in my Hyperledger-besu Private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, mining, besu

I have been using Hyperledger-Besu's [quickstart guide](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/1.3.0/Tutorials/Quickstarts/Private-Network-Quickstart/) to build my private blockchain (with ibft2 as consensus algorithm) on an AWS instance, which basically just clones that repo https://github.com/PegaSysEng/besu-sample-networks
and run the scripts, anyways everything works fine but suddenly maybe after some days the mining process gets stopped resulting in no response from the dapp.

I figured out I have to restart the network, without erasing the containers, then mining process works again.
But i can not figure out why the mining process stops or why it even works again after restarting, and this is annoying as there is no indicator when it will stop or any error handling.

Currently I have also modified the scripts here https://github.com/PegaSysEng/besu-sample-networks to make the network Free-gas as explained in that guide https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Configure/FreeGas/ but I still have the same problem.

so If anyone had the same problem or can think of a solution it would be great, thanks.

Comment: can't leave comment as too new. We're running into the same problem at the moment. For us, it stops mining as soon as we push a transaction through it. We're running a slightly modified setup from the tutorial with EthSigners. Did you get this solved Youssef?

Comment: No I haven't found any solutions for now, but I have noticed when using a better machine "bigger RAM and storage" that problem is not repeating now. I still have no clue of the reason or the solution.